How can I resolve flutter app build fail for android metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1?
I have already followed this answer to try fix this issue but no luck.
The build works 100% on iOS Simulator, but failing on Android Emulator with below:
The class is loaded from .gradle/caches/transforms-3/c3f0666cf8984b118654915928619821/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.9.0.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
e: .pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/stripe_android-9.6.0+2/android/src/main/kotlin/com/reactnativestripesdk/utils/Mappers.kt: (926, 7): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':stripe_android:compileDebugKotlin'.
> A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.GradleCompilerRunnerWithWorkers$GradleKotlinCompilerWorkAction
   > Compilation error. See log for more details

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 33s

┌─ Flutter Fix ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ [!] Your project requires a newer version of the Kotlin Gradle plugin.                     │
│ Find the latest version on https://kotlinlang.org/docs/releases.html#release-details, then │
│ update /wwwdir/doclink_ios/android/build.gradle:                         │
│ ext.kotlin_version = '<latest-version>'                                                    │
└────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
Error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

build.gradle file:
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.9.20'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.15'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}


pubspec.yaml file:
name: doclink
description: A new Flutter project.

# The following line prevents the package from being accidentally published to
# pub.dev using `flutter pub publish`. This is preferred for private packages.
publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev

# The following defines the version and build number for your application.
# A version number is three numbers separated by dots, like 1.2.43
# followed by an optional build number separated by a +.
# Both the version and the builder number may be overridden in flutter
# build by specifying --build-name and --build-number, respectively.
# In Android, build-name is used as versionName while build-number used as versionCode.
# Read more about Android versioning at https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning
# In iOS, build-name is used as CFBundleShortVersionString while build-number is used as CFBundleVersion.
# Read more about iOS versioning at
# https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html
# In Windows, build-name is used as the major, minor, and patch parts
# of the product and file versions while build-number is used as the build suffix.
version: 1.0.1

environment:
  sdk: '>=2.18.5 <3.0.0'

# Dependencies specify other packages that your package needs in order to work.
# To automatically upgrade your package dependencies to the latest versions
# consider running `flutter pub upgrade --major-versions`. Alternatively,
# dependencies can be manually updated by changing the version numbers below to
# the latest version available on pub.dev. To see which dependencies have newer
# versions available, run `flutter pub outdated`.
dependency_overrides:
  intl: ^0.18.1
  package_info_plus: ^4.0.1
  http: ^1.0.0

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_localizations:
    sdk: flutter


  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.6

  firebase_core: ^2.4.1
  cloud_firestore: ^4.4.5
  firebase_messaging: ^14.5.0

  #------------  Service, Permission, Video, Image, State Management ------------#
  intl: ^0.17.0
  get: ^4.6.5
  permission_handler: ^10.2.0
  agora_rtc_engine: ^6.2.2
  shared_preferences: ^2.0.17
  image_picker: ^0.8.6+1
  video_thumbnail: ^0.5.3
  webview_flutter: ^4.4.4
  video_player: ^2.6.0
  timezone: ^0.9.1

  #------------  Google map ------------#
  google_maps_flutter: ^2.2.3
  geolocator: ^9.0.2

  #------------  UI ------------#
  intl_phone_number_input: ^0.7.2
  dotted_border: ^2.0.0+3
  table_calendar: ^3.0.8
  syncfusion_flutter_charts: ^20.4.38
  cached_network_image: ^3.2.3
  qr_code_scanner: ^1.0.1
  url_launcher: ^6.1.10
  flutter_rating_bar: ^4.0.1
  shimmer: ^2.0.0
  photo_view: ^0.14.0
  collection: ^1.17.0

  #------------  Notification ------------#
  flutter_local_notifications: ^14.0.0+1
  flutter_app_badger: ^1.5.0
  qr_flutter: ^4.1.0
  open_filex: ^4.3.4
  syncfusion_flutter_pdf: ^20.4.54
  flutter_stripe: ^9.4.0
  razorpay_flutter: ^1.3.5
  flutterwave_standard: ^1.0.8
  toggle_switch: ^2.1.0
  multiselect: ^0.1.0
  firebase_analytics: ^10.7.1
  signature: ^5.4.1
  device_preview: ^1.1.0
  flutter_paystack: ^1.0.7
  flutter_paypal: ^0.2.0
  firebase_auth: ^4.16.0
  

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

  # The "flutter_lints" package below contains a set of recommended lints to
  # encourage good coding practices. The lint set provided by the package is
  # activated in the `analysis_options.yaml` file located at the root of your
  # package. See that file for information about deactivating specific lint
  # rules and activating additional ones.
  flutter_lints: ^2.0.0

# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec

# The following section is specific to Flutter packages.
flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true
  generate: true
  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  assets:
    - assets/
    - assets/icon/
    - assets/image/
    - assets/json/

  # An image asset can refer to one or more resolution-specific "variants", see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#resolution-aware

  # For details regarding adding assets from package dependencies, see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#from-packages

  # To add custom fonts to your application, add a fonts section here,
  # in this "flutter" section. Each entry in this list should have a
  # "family" key with the font family name, and a "fonts" key with a
  # list giving the asset and other descriptors for the font. For
  # example:
  fonts:
    - family: black
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/fonts/Montserrat-Black.ttf
    - family: bold
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/fonts/Montserrat-Bold.ttf
    - family: extraBold
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/fonts/Montserrat-ExtraBold.ttf
    - family: extraLight
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/fonts/Montserrat-ExtraLight.ttf
    - family: light
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/fonts/Montserrat-Light.ttf
    - family: medium
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/fonts/Montserrat-Medium.ttf
    - family: regular
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/fonts/Montserrat-Regular.ttf
    - family: semiBold
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/fonts/Montserrat-SemiBold.ttf
    - family: thin
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/fonts/Montserrat-Thin.ttf



  # For details regarding fonts from package dependencies,
  # see https://flutter.dev/custom-fonts/#from-packages
flutter_intl:
  enabled: true

I'm hoping someone can give advice or feedback on how to fix this issue.

try to open your android folder in android studio and invalidate cache..

Thanks @Yakubu. I am trying to sync now. I use Intellij but will try a sync in Android Studio.

@designtocode either update stripe version or use kotlin version 1.7.1

Thanks for advice @Maveňツ I'll try update stripe and see. How would I go about updating Kotlin? Is that through Android Studio?

Hi @Maveňツ @Yakuba I tried all your solutions but managed to build by changing the plugin version from 1.7.0 in android/settings.gradle file id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android" version "1.9.0" apply false. Not sure if you can explain why this change would make the build pass. I'm still using the same Gradle, Kotlin and Java versions.

You can try

Open your flutterApp/android folder in android studio


for mac


run ./gradlew cleanBuildCache


on Windows:


run gradlew cleanBuildCache

Invalidate caches.



and let your gradle sync


Hi @Yakuba thanks for this. I think this pointed me in the right direction for debugging, seeing `Execution failed for task ':gradle:compileGroovy'.

BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit '/development/flutter/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/src/main/groovy/app_plugin_loader.groovy' Unsupported class file major version 65
` Looks like there's a compatibility between Java and Gradle. Trying to update Gradle now.


all you need to update is gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties

the issue is most likely because you have higher java version.. another approach is for you to change your java version  android studio is pointing to..

before
plugins {
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-plugin-loader" version "1.0.0"
    id "com.android.application" version "7.3.0" apply false
    id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android" version "1.7.10" apply false
}  

after
plugins {
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-plugin-loader" version "1.0.0"
    id "com.android.application" version "7.3.0" apply false
    id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android" version "1.9.20" apply false
} 

